# how to create a table with result set in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table to store result set of another query.

I have tried this:

```
create table avgcost_product (
    name varchar(50),
    productnumber varchar(50),
    averagecost money
)
```

After creating table I tried this query:

```
INSERT into avgcost_product SELECT * FROM
(SELECT p.[Name], p.ProductNumber,
        CONVERT(varchar, cost.AvgCost,1) as 'Average Cost'
FROM Production.Product p
CROSS APPLY fnGetAvgCost(p.ProductID) as cost
WHERE cost.AvgCost IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cost.AvgCost desc)
```

But it shows error like:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 284
>
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

How I can write data I need in my table?

Comment: Yes, it's telling you that the `ORDER BY` is pointless. Tables don't **have** any inherent order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `ORDER BY` from the inner select or you can even simplify your query even more:

```
INSERT into avgcost_product 
SELECT p.[Name]
       , p.ProductNumber
       , CONVERT(varchar, cost.AvgCost,1) as 'Average Cost'
FROM Production.Product p
CROSS APPLY fnGetAvgCost(p.ProductID) as cost
WHERE cost.AvgCost IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just to add to this. SQL by definition doesn't store data in a particular order. That's why it's so important to use ORDER BY when actually retrieving the data if you do want it in a certain order.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create the table on the fly using [SELECT INTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx#Anchor_3):

```
SELECT  p.[Name], 
        p.ProductNumber,
        CONVERT(varchar, cost.AvgCost,1) as [Average Cost] 
INTO avgcost_product
FROM Production.Product p
CROSS APPLY fnGetAvgCost(p.ProductID) as cost
WHERE cost.AvgCost IS NOT NULL
```